# imagemagick 'identify command' error only from safari when uploading photo after processing

Tags: image-processing, file-upload, safari, imagemagick, paperclip

I believe this error is a problem with my javascript in Safari (and mobile safari) as I can upload photos from chrome no problem.

What I've got is a web-based mobile app, and users need to be able to upload photos. 
But I don't need/want the photos in high resolution, so I stick them in a canvas, resize, capture the canvas toDataURL, and convert to a blob. Simple enough, right ;)

I suspect the offending javascript is in here

```
  var binary = atob(imgTag.src.split(',')[1]);
            var array = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
                array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
             }


    var formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('photo[image]',new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)]));
```

but I have to admit, I'm not familiar with streaming images into strings, etc. etc. I followed a selection of blogs and answers here on StackOverflow to get me this far.

I'd be happy with an answer that worked either server or client-side. I've tried changing to an earlier version of the cocaine gem, as that solved the problem for somebody else, but I'm locked into my version because I'm using Paperclip 3.1.3 and rails 3.2.3 with Sass and all the other good stuff.

The error from my console is

```
Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/blob20121214-5750-185epy9[0]'
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /tmp/blob20121214-5750-185epy9 is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob to convert canvas to blob on all platforms, and it works in safari on ios, which is what I needed.